# Sqldelight database schema not generated

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I have a KMM project and want to use `SqlDelight` library, but when I build the project  database schema not generated and table entities also.

```
actual class DatabaseDriverFactory(private val context: Context) {
    actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
               //Unresolved reference: CoreDb
        return AndroidSqliteDriver(CoreDb.Schema, context, "test.db")
    }
}
```

I have defined sqldelight folder inside my shared module and also created folder for feature generated kotlin classes as it is configured in `gradle.build.kts` and also have one `*.sq` file inside `sqldelight` folder

```
sqldelight {
  database("CoreDb") {
    packageName = "com.example.app.core.database"
    sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    dialect = "sqlite:3.24"
  }
}
```

When I run `generateSqlDelightInterface` task I just see those log

```
> Task :core:generateAndroidDebugCoreDbInterface NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:generateAndroidReleaseCoreDbInterface NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:generateIosMainCoreDbInterface NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:generateMetadataCommonMainCoreDbInterface NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:generateMetadataMainCoreDbInterface NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:generateSqlDelightInterface UP-TO-DATE
can't register checkAndroidModules

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 311ms
1:40:36 PM: Task execution finished 'generateSqlDelightInterface'.
```

Here is my full `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  kotlin("plugin.serialization")
  id("com.android.library")
  id("kotlin-android-extensions")
  id("koin")
  id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

repositories {
  gradlePluginPortal()
  google()
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
  }
  maven {
    url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/ekito/koin")
  }
}
kotlin {
  android()

  val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
    if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
      ::iosArm64
    else
      ::iosX64

  iOSTarget("ios") {
    binaries {
      framework {
        baseName = "core"
      }
    }
  }
  val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"
  val ktor_version = "1.4.2"
  val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
  val koin_version = "3.0.0-alpha-4"
  val sqlDelight = "1.4.4"

  sourceSets {

    val commonMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")

        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")


        implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelight")
        // SqlDelight extension
        implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:$sqlDelight")
        // Koin for Kotlin
        implementation("org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version")
        //shared preferences
        implementation("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.6.3")
      }
    }
    val commonTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
        implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
      }
    }
    val androidMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
        implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelight")
      }
    }
    val androidTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
        implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
      }
    }
    val iosMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
        implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelight")
      }
    }

  
    val iosTest by getting
  }
}



android {
  compileSdkVersion(29)
  sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion(23)
    targetSdkVersion(29)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
      isMinifyEnabled = false
    }
  }
}
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
  group = "build"
  val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
  val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
  val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
  val framework =
    kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios").binaries.getFramework(mode)
  inputs.property("mode", mode)
  dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
  val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
  from({ framework.outputDirectory })
  into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)


sqldelight {
  database("CoreDb") {
    packageName = "com.example.app.core.database"
    sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    dialect = "sqlite:3.24"
  }
}
```

and for top level `build.gradle`

`classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:$sqlDelight"`

**Update**

My project folder structure

```
root
  app
    src
      ...

  core //(kmm shared module)
    androidMain
        com.example.app.core
            database
    commonMain
        com.example.app.core
            database
            repository
            ...
            sqldelight
    iosMain
        com.example.app.core
            database
```

Comment: Could you please post your project folder structure?

Comment: @shadowsheep I have updated the post

Comment: `sqldelight` folder with your `*.sq` files should be put inside `commonMain` directly

Comment: I'll investigate more

Comment: thanks a lot I'm trying to fix that since yesterday

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that you have your `sqldelight` folder, where you put your `*.sq` files, in the wrong place.

It should be put inside `commonMain` directly and inside `sqldelight` you must specify your package.

If your package is `com.example.kmmtest003.database` your folder structure should be:

```
- commonMain
    - sqldelight
      - com
        - example
          - kmmtest003
            - database
```

And here you must put your `*.sq` files.

[image]

**OTHER POSSIBLE REASONS**

As IgorGanapolsky pointed out, this same issue could be caused also by an incompatible gradle plugin version.

Comment: I tried that and it says: Task :core:generateAndroidDebugCoreDbInterface FAILED
/Users/mrkt/StudioProjects/projectName/core/src/commonMain/sqldelight/User.sq line 1:0 - SqlDelight files must be placed in a package directory.

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili got it! You have to put the package folder structure inside the folder `sqldeglight` as the one you specify in your `build.gradle.kts:sqldelght` section.

Comment: Nice and thanks, didn't checked yet. Will check it today asap

Comment: This isn't the real problem causing such an issue.

Comment: Hi, @IgorGanapolsky can you elaborate more?

Comment: @shadowsheep I had this issue, and it wasn't due to wrong location of `sqldelight`.  It was due to incompatible gradle plugin version.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky so that could be another cause of this issue. But I think that both my answer and yout commet could be usefull. So I update the answer with also this possible cause. Thx!

Comment: This is the issue I was having with the latest KMM and 1.5.3 of sqldelight. It doesn't state that you need to create these actual directories in the Kotlin tutorial. By creating directories that match the packageName provided you will be able to generate your named database. Thanks @shadowsheep

Comment: I am getting this issue in Compose Desktop project and I dont have a "commonMain" module. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cgb_pandey I guess you don't have a kotlin multiplatform setup. But it doesn't matter. If your source folder is not `commonMain` but another one, just follow your package name folder structure convention and all should work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This might help someone in the future...I had created a directory in KMM, and it was named `sqldelight.com.package.database`

I thought this was a proper package, but realized this was not being caught by SQLDelight, and thus my schema wasn't being generated.

I needed to create the structure as a proper directory structure (and then everything worked):

```
sqldelight
  com
    package
      database
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you can change the folder to kotlin if you want the SQL code to be in the same directory with your code:

```
sqldelight {
  database("CoreDb") {
    ...
    sourceFolders = listOf("kotlin")
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help if you have multiple databases and configuring version >=2.0.0

You need separate top level directory for each database.

The second/incorrect folder structure worked with version 1.x but on 2.x will produce

> SqlDelight files must be placed in a package directory

#### Correct

File structure

```
src
└─ main
   └─ sqdelight-db1
      └─ com/example/db1
         ├─ Team.sq
         └─ Player.sq
   └─ sqdelight-db2
      └─ com/example/db2
         ├─ Team.sq
         └─ Player.sq
```

Config

```kotlin
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("db1") {
            packageName.set("com.example.db1")
            srcDirs.setFrom("src/main/sqldelight-db1")
        }
        create("db2") {
            packageName.set("com.example.db2")
            srcDirs.setFrom("src/main/sqldelight-db2")
        }
    }
}
```

#### Incorrect - one that will produce error

File structure

```
src
└─ main
   └─ sqdelight
      └─ com/example/db1
         ├─ Team.sq
         └─ Player.sq
      └─ com/example/db2 <-- This is wrong
         ├─ Team.sq
         └─ Player.sq
```

Config

```kotlin
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("db1") {
            packageName.set("com.example.db1")
            srcDirs.setFrom("src/main/sqldelight/com/example/db1") <-- This is wrong
        }
        create("db2") {
            packageName.set("com.example.db2")
            srcDirs.setFrom("src/main/sqldelight/com/example/db2") <-- This is wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Figuring this out on my own  was such a pain. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and I guess the reason was that I tried to place `sqldelight` not in `commonMain` but in my `jvmMain` package in a standard KMM project.

Moving `sqldelight` to `commonMain` helped, but I hope there is a solution someone here can share to configure `sqldelight` in `jvmMain` or other platform specific sources.